# Facebook Page Tab App isn't showing up for other users

Tags: facebook, tabs

So I recently made Penn State Worthington Scranton's Facebook page.

I added a page tab app called "PSWS Social Media Hub".

It shows up for me when I am logged in, but it doesn't show up for anyone who is just searching for the page. How can I get it to show up for everyone else?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you taken the app live?

Answer (score 0):

Questions:

- Have you put the app live?
- Have you created the App Details page?
- Is it a canvas app?

The docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter#creating are stating

> We encourage all developers to create an App Details page so that the app appears in search and can be made eligible for listing in the App Center.

For Canvas apps, apparantly 10 MAUs are neccessary to be shown in the search results (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas#search):

> When your app exceeds 10 monthly active users it will be automatically queued to be included in the search index the next time we rebuild our search index (we rebuild every 2-4 weeks). After the index is rebuilt your app will be discoverable via Search.

Comment: By far the most likely thing to be wrong is that the app is still in development mode - app center listings don't affect the app's visiblity

Comment: How do I take it out of development mode?

Comment: @Igy He's explicitly saying that it doesn't show up in search. And that the app is maybe private is only one possible reason that it isn't shown (though it's the most likely case, as you mention)

Comment: @BillWidmer Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and select your app. Go to "Status/Review" on the left side. Then, on top of the loaded page, there's a switch for taking the app to the public.

Comment: Thank all of you so much for your quick replies, I have successfully turned it to public!

Comment: Great! If I could help then please accept my answer.

Comment: he said the tab wasn't displayed on the page, not that the app wasn't searchable